# How should I interpret these symbols in multivariable calculus?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

I am essentially (as in: essential singularity) confused by "change of variables" formula of two-variable function.

All functions below are $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, meaning a functions of two variables. So let there be $f$, $g$, $u$ and $v$ of that form, and additionally impose $g$ by $g(u(x,y), v(x,y)) = f(x, y)$.

Often in physics one would then talk about the following objects, none of which
I ever understood:

- $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ - I would interpret this as $\partial_1 g$, but apparently one is allowed to write $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} $$
- $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$ - $u$ is a function, not a label of an argument, and yet I am to believe that
  $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} $$
  where again $x$ and $y$ are not functions, so $\partial_u x$, $\partial_v x$ have no meaning.

The matter is further complicated when one writes out the arguments:
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial u} (u(a, b), v(a,b)) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} (a, b) + \frac{\partial g}{\partial v} (u(a, b), v(a,b)) \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} (a,b)$$ is supposed to be $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(a, b)$ or $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(u(a,b), v(a,b))$?

It always seemed to me that one tacitly promotes $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ to a vector space $(\mathbb{R}^2, +, \cdot)$ and all functions are then converted into functions of vector variables (e.g. $\tilde{f}(\vec{x}) = f(\vec{x} \cdot \vec{i}, \vec{x} \cdot \vec{j})$). But this scheme is doomed to fail in general if the domains of the three variables together do not form a vector space.

**How should I interpret partial derivatives contructs such as those listed?** A reference to a multivariable calculus book that is very strict about this would be helpful too.

Comment: $\partial x/\partial u$ is, I think, supposed to be interpreted using the inverse or implicit function theorems, that under certain conditions we know $u$ is in some sense invertible so that $x$ may depend partially on $u(x,y)$ (locally)

Comment: But then it is a completely different beast that $\partial_x u$, right? Not only one may not always we able to invert $u$, $v$ system, it also requires that $u$ and $v$ share the meaning of $x$ (that it denotes the first argument, and not for example $u(x,y)$, $v(y,x)$.

Comment: $\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}$Most of this boils down to very widespread abuse of notation when it comes to derivatives. The same thing happens in one variable as well, as it's unfortunately not uncommon to see the chain rule written as $\frac{\dd y}{\dd x}=\frac{\dd y}{\dd u}\cdot\frac{\dd u}{\dd x}$, when it really should be written as $\frac{\dd}{\dd x}(f(g(x)))=f'(g(x))g'(x)$. In particular, the first way is quite frankly wrong, as it appears to suggest that the right hand side (when you evaluate at the point $x$) should be $f'(x)g'(x)$, which is both wrong, and not necessarily defined.

Comment: A big problem is that for some reason a lot of authors use $\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}$ to mean both $f'$ and $f'(x)$, which is very problematic

Comment: I agree that Leibniz notation for single variable is very confusing, and actually mixing Leibniz and Newton as @Lorago did in the comment makes it even worse. One should for single variable case write the full statement: if $h(x) = f(g(x))$ for all $x$, then $h'(x) = f'(g(x)) g'(x)$. Then it's always clear w.r.t. what the derivative is taken.

Comment: May be helpful to always write explicitly function (composition of functions) and its argument. In your first case, for example, $\partial_1 g$ will be unambiguous when you write $(g\circ (u, v))(x,y)$ and/or $g(x,y)$.

Comment: @zkutch I would have thought that $(g \circ (u, v))(x,y) \neq g(x,y)$ unless $u$, $v$ are identities? $\partial_1 g$ seems pretty unambiguous to me: it is a function $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is produced from $g$ by taking derivative w.r.t. to the first argument

Comment: $(x,y)$ is written only to designate variables and I didn't mean, that they are same in mentioned two examples. I wanted emphasize, that explicit form eliminates ambiguity.

Comment: The title could be more specific; e.g. "these symbols" refers to partial derivatives.

Comment: @mr_e_man I have no problem interpreting partial derivatives. The definition is clear to me (derivative w.r.t. one variable, other kept fixed). I have a problem interpreting symbols like $\partial_u f$ that get thrown around but (in my head) undefined when taking the definitions strictly.